# Android activity flow & navigation up/back

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android application that has 4 activities :

A -> B -> C -> D

When I'm going from A to B, from B to C, or from C to D, I put some extras in the Intent.

I guess navigation for something like that is quite simple: there's no need to redefine the back button, and for the "up" action bar button, a simple "finish()" would be to correct way to do it (?)

Now, the problem is that from A, I can also go directly to D. Still no need to redefine the back button, it will go back to A, and that's what I want, but for the "up" button, it must go to C, and from C, up will lead to B, ...

What is the correct way to do that?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: Stephane, thanks for the tick, and you probably want to see my revised answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the flow between the various activities explicitly, I call `finish()` in each activity when I respond to user input by starting a new activity:

```
startActivity(intentForNewActivity);
finish();
```

That leads to that instance of the orignal Activity being destroyed. In each activity I create an Intent to start up the activity I want to go back to. Then write:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(intentWhereIWantToGoNext);
    finish();
}
```

I originally wrote here that I called finish() in onStop(), which does work while the app remains running, but does not give the desired result if the app is stopped for any reason. Sorry for the confusion, and thanks to PravinCG, who, while his comments were not entirely on the right track, at least made me think more carefully.

Comment: This is not recommended, you are trying to manage the activity stack and for complex stacks this might not work. Besides if you want to achieve this you can simply put android:nohistory in the manifest for each activity.

Comment: Stack? There is no stack, each activity is destroyed when it becomes invisible and recreated from nothing when it becomes visible. I agree that it's error-prone to have to program all the right transitions, but is there anything else I can get wrong if the activities generally do not have stored state?

Comment: There is an activity stack, in the sense the order. And you are wrong that the activities are destroyed everytime they become invisible. Kindly refer to Activity LifeCycle of Android. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle

Comment: I'm sorry, I must be terribly confused here. In the answer above, I stated that I called finish() in every onStop(), so that as soon as an activity became invisible, it would be destroyed. The activity lifecycle document suggests that is the case. Am I misunderstanding it, or misunderstanding you, please?

Comment: No your are right that after calling finish, it actually destroys the activity. But remember everytime you have to reinitialize the entire activity by calling onCreate, even in case of resumed activity which will hit the performance.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. And you did make me think enough to correct my answer in another way - see above!

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to actually have the same stack but use extras to perform the toggle.

For Instance: When you want to go from A -> D
go from A->B->C->D and use intents to handle whether you want to simply bypass activity or display it. Same is the case in reverse order user resultIntent for that.

Comment: An additional question: how do you bypass an activiy?

I tried something like that:

`if (extras.getInt("goToC") > 0) {
Intent i = new Intent(this, C.class);
startActivity(i);
}`
I put it at the end of the "onCreate" method of B activity (to go from A to C), but it displays for a few milliseconds the B activity. How can I go directly to C without displaying the B activity at all?

Comment: Ideally you can check this even before setContentView there might still be few ms lag though.

Comment: Yes, there's lag, so I'll try the solution proposed by @emrys57

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code before the last bracket.

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
```